# How to extract fields enveloped in quotes in NiFi?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, data-cleaning

I have some pipe delimited files. Each field is bounded by quotes like this.

```
"Created_Date__c"|"CreatedById"|"CreatedDate"|"Guid_c"
"2020-03-02 00:00:00"|"0053i000002XCpAAG"|"2020-03-02 16:01:34"|"94bf83ccf9daf610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD"
"2020-03-03 00:00:00"|"0053i000002XCpAAG"|"2020-03-03 09:15:56"|"1a4bb238cdedd610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD"
"2020-03-03 00:00:00"|"0053i000002XCpAAG"|"2020-03-03 09:52:33"|"22408baca6fee610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD"
```

I need to cleanse this data and the needs to look like this.

```
Created_Date__c|CreatedById|CreatedDate|Guid_c
2020-03-02 00:00:00|0053i000002XCpAAG|2020-03-02 16:01:34|94bf83ccf9daf610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD
2020-03-03 00:00:00|0053i000002XCpAAG|2020-03-03 09:15:56|1a4bb238cdedd610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD
2020-03-03 00:00:00|0053i000002XCpAAG|2020-03-03 09:52:33|22408baca6fee610VgnVCM100000307882a2RCRD
```

I tried using ReplaceText with these configurations.
search value - `^"(.*)"$` and Replacement Value - `$1`. But these configurations is not working and the file is routing to failure. not sure what might be the issue.

open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not to set search value to `"` and replacement to empty string?

Comment: what the other parameters of replacetext? what is the size of file?

Comment: Hi Daggett, I might have quotes in some fields. I don't want to replace all quotes with empty spaces. I just want to remove quotes that surrounds on every field. I have multiple files and Their individual size is less than 15Mb

Comment: Show an example with quotes inside value. IMHO: it's almost impossible in this case to use regex...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use `"(.*?)"` regex instead of `^"(.*)"$`.
Some online services such as https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html can be useful for testing the regex replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here is a `ConvertRecord` processor, have `CSVReader` with infer schema + changing the csv sep to your own |, and a `CSVRecordSetWritter` with Option `Quote Mode` set to `Do Not Quote Values` and also set your sep as per your need.

Comment: it does work - 100% , can you post waht you did so far ?